# Doesn't Ubuntu 13.10 support the hostapd nl80211 driver?

Tags: wireless, hostapd

I could use hostapd-2.1 to set wireless AP in Ubuntu 12.04.

But in Ubuntu 13.10 it failed. The same source code for hostapd-2.1 was failing
in 13.10.

The error message:

```
nl80211 : Failed to set wlan0 as Ap
nl80211 : driver initialization failed
```

What should I do to modify hostapd-2.1 to work on Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: Please give us some more details. What exactly are you attempting? What hardware are you using? When and where exactly do you see that error message? What commands do you run to cause it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in the new hostapd (2.0+) that is on the ubuntu 13+ versions is now stopping on an error that it used to ignore.

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22845597/3495026 )

If one turns off the programs that are accessing the resource, hostapd has a chance to grab it and work.

In Ubuntu desktop 14.04 beta, a solution is to turn off the programs that are using the wlan in question.

This worked for me:

```
sudo nmcli nm wifi off
sudo rfkill unblock wlan
```

then hostapd can start normally from command line. Of course, if you want hostapd to start on boot you must insure that the network manager is not grabbing the resource ahead of time.